# Can Xamarin Profiler work with .net 6+ apps

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, .net-6.0, .net-7.0, xamarin-profiler

I've been attempting to use the Xamarin Profiler on .net 7 iOS and Android Xamarin projects unsuccessfully both on Visual Studio Mac (with enterprise license) and Visual Studio Enterprise 2022. In both environments and with both projects the Xamarin Profiler will get stuck on "Opening path\filename.mlpd". When I inspect the mlpd, it is always empty.

I tried creating new projects using the VS templates for iOS, Android, and a Maui (I've tried both .net 6 and 7,) and again tried to use the Xamarin Profiler on each. Every one resulted in the same thing, an empty mlpd.

If I create new projects using old VS templates for iOS and Android (not .net 6+), the mlpd will become populated, and profiling works.

From what I can tell, the Xamarin Profiler does not work on .net 6+ iOS, Android, or Maui projects, both on Visual Studio Mac and Windows.

*VS Enterprise Windows v17.5.3, Xamarin Profiler Windows v1.8.0.53*

*VS Mac v17.5.3, Xamarin Profiler Mac v14.1*

Comment: Can this [wiki on the github about Profiling .NET MAUI Apps](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Profiling-.NET-MAUI-Apps) help you?

Comment: This could be very useful for profiling, but it isn't about using the Xamarin Profiler (which Microsoft promotes, and essentially charges for.)

Comment: But the official document said the Xamarin Profiler is used for the xamarin app.